# SQL Server 2016 to oracle 18c database migration

Tags: sql-server, oracle, migration, sql-server-2016, oracle18c

I'm trying to migrate a database created in SQL Server 2016 to Oracle 18c.

Both database instances are installed in VMs.

However the migration fails providing a message which I could not understand as I'm not that deep into Oracle RDBMS.

Now, both VMs have 4GB of RAM and each one is used to host the specific RDBMS (SQL Server 2016 & Oracle 18c respectively)

Both RDBMSs were installed with default options. The origin database (SQL Server 2016) is a very simple one, no triggers or stored procedures or anything like that. It only has PK-FK constraints for table relations.

The target database is an empty DB (or User as Oracle calls it) with all privileges provided in the options.

I'm providing the screenshots below following the steps from SQL Developer Migration Wizard.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

[image: Step 5]

[image: Step 6]

[image: Step 7]

[image: Step 8]

[image: Step 9]

[image: Error shown]

SQL Server 2016 OS is Windows Server 2016, Oracle 18c OS is 2008R2 Datacenter edition.

The only option I've checked was to truncate the target DB. Please let me know If you need any further details that can help.